# What's the difference between a Real Literal and Type Casting in C#?

Tags: c#

Trying to understand the difference between the two. For example:

```
if(value >= 100M){...}
```

*or*

```
if(value >= (decimal)100){...}
```

Also, what's the industry standard? I see a lot of each and just want to make sure I fully understand the difference and am within best practices.

Comment: Since you're casting from other constant values, the compiler will in all likelihood treat the value as the appropriate type and do no further conversion. You'll end up with equivalent blocks of code in the end. But if it was non-constant, then it would perform a conversion.

Comment: @JeffMercado If it weren't constant, you couldn't write `M` :)

Comment: @Rob - Jeff is clearly talking about the second `if`, not the first with the `M`.

Comment: Casting a floating point literal to decimal is generally a mistake.  Compare var v1 = (decimal)1.23456789012345678; versus var v2 = 1.23456789012345678m;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a conclusion, C# compiler generates same result from either code, so you can use whichever you like.

I compiled your code and decompiled with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/):

Before compile

```
var value = 1m;
if (value >= 100M)
{
}

if (value >= (decimal)100)
{
}

//This is the most simple
if (value >= 100)
{
}
```

Compile and decompile

```
decimal one = decimal.One;
bool flag = one >= 100m;
if (flag)
{
}
bool flag2 = one >= 100m;
if (flag2)
{
}
bool flag3 = one >= 100m;
if (flag3)
{
}
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on what you did on that second section of code?

Comment: well, I decompiled compiler generated binary from 1st section code to show these "if sentence" are equal.